# Li-Po battery standards for EU & US

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, ce

I am selecting a  Lithium Polymer battery for a general low power electronic device with wireless communication which we plan to sell in EU and US. My reference is following documents:

- IEC-62368: "Audio/video, information and communication technology
  equipment Part 1: Safety requirements"
- IEEE-1725: "IEEE Standard for Rechargeable Batteries for Cellular Telephones"

According to IEC-62368, battery needs to meet:

- IEC-62133

According to IEEE-1725, battery needs to meet:

- UN 38.3
- UL 1642 for cell
- UL 2054 for pack
- IEC-62133

So, now I am contacting battery manufacturers to find a battery that meets our application specs and also conforms the battery standards. It turns out that it is very difficult to find a fully certified pack model that suits your needs.

I would like to ask you few questions, perhaps you can help me by clarifying some points:

1. To conform with regulations, battery charger needs NTC input for temperature monitoring during charging. So naturally I am looking for a battery pack with NTC output. The manufacturers offer me some models that don't have NTC but are certified. Would adding external NTC invalidate their safety certifications?
2. We cannot afford to pay for battery's UL certification. Is both UL1642 and UL2054 mandatory for US market? I have read that some retailers won't accept products that are not UL certified. Is it true?
3. Do I need to ask for EU battery directive, ROHS, and EN-62133 as well?
4. Is there anything else I need to look for?

I would appreciate if someone can shed light on these topics.

Thank you.

Comment: UL certification isn't mandatory in the US, but certification from *some* testing lab recognised by the US is, and UL is probably the biggest name on that list.

Comment: What about if internationally recognized company conducts test for IEC-62133. Would it be then sufficient for US market?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Battery regulations is a big topic. It's not just the requirements of various nations, it's what the freight companies require as well. So while you might not need UL approval just to sell the product in USA, you might need to transport the product there. And so on. Everyone out there is trying to make dealing with batteries as complicated as possible.

Comment: Hi, can you clarify this requirement "battery charger needs NTC input for temperature monitoring during charging." where is this requirement specifically for the charger coming from ? If it is just "monitoring" this can be done by some other means other than the charger itself ...

Comment: I think to answer some of your questions (or at least to get you on the right path) you may need to include further info, like total power requirement of the product, max current drawn etc.

Comment: UL2054 is a lengthy and expensive process from what I know, and so IEC62133 is more suitable for battery packs for low power applications. To the best of my knowledge En62368 references a list of acceptable standards for Li batteries and packs, amongst which IEC62133, UL1973 and UL2054 is most likely pertinent to your application...

Comment: Varta has a list of ready made off-the-shelf IEC62133 certified batteries and packs. This may get you going quickly in the short term (or long term) until you get the volumes to justify a custom pack to certify to IEC62133 ... Design a ready made pack into the product, whilst allowing for space for a certified custom pack for switching to later on ...

Comment: @citizen Hi, regarding NTC requirement, it is written in M4.2.2 (ASNZS62368): "The
charging of the battery shall be stopped when the temperature of the battery exceeds the highest specified charging temperature. The battery charging circuit shall limit the current to the value specified by the battery manufacturer when the battery temperature is lower than the lowest specified charging temperature." The standard is the adaptation of IEC62368 to Australia/NZ, it is the only free version that I was able to find on internet.

Comment: @UserRR ahhh thanks ... do you have a link to ASNZ62368 by any chance ?

Comment: @UserRR. never mind I googled it ... cheers